# opening domain with wkWebView .info domain not opening but .com is

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to open a `.info` domain in my WkWebView but it does not load.

`.com` loads perfectly fine but with `.info` its just a blank page

```
let url = URL(string: "https://info.info")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
openWebViewer.load(request)
```

Comment: Have you tried other `.info` domains to ensure the problem is not with the domain itself?

Comment: Hey, problem was i have "https//" instead of "http//". Thank you sir!